# Easy: Graphs of Straight Line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

[image]

I can't exactly figure out how to work this out.

Well I know the equation for a straight line is $y = mx + c$

$c = gradient$

Therefore if I multiply $3$ by the number $x$ to get the gradient $6$ and $2$ I can work out which is line is which...

With $y = 3(x + 2)$ I tried to expand but then I got confused.

Can someone explain in easy terms? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your main trouble is expanding the equation $$y= 3(x+2)$$
The distributive property goes as follows, $$a(b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c$$
Thus,  $$3(x+2) = 3x + (3 \cdot 2) = 3x+6$$
In this equation the 3 represents the slope and the 6 represents the y-intercept.  You should now be able to correctly identify which line is which.

Answer (score 6):

Do you know the distributive property?
a(b+c)=ab+ac

If you can write in slope-intercept form...that is y=mx+b..you can determine the y-intercept is b since when x=0 y=b.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactical side note: $m$ is called the *gradient*, $c$ is called the $y$-*intercept*.
To find the correct equation for $A$, just look at the $y$-intercept of $A$: it's $6$.

This means that $A$ must be of the form $y = mx + 6$, wich only one of your equations satisfies. Note that

$$a\cdot(b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c$$
for any real numbers (also variables) $a,b$ and $c$.